# background-color: inherit in Safari doesn't update when parent updates

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

On a website I've been working on, I need to specify that some elements have the same background color as the body itself. Rather than specifying the colors twice, I added this CSS rule:

```css
* {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

The site also has a pair of switches to toggle light mode vs dark mode and high-contrast vs low-contrast mode.

For some reason, in Safari this doesn't always work right. Sometimes, when I turn off dark mode, the background of some elements stays dark. Interestingly, elements with `color: inherit` update the text color but not the background color.

This isn't very consistent, but what I've noticed (in Safari iOS 16.3 and 16.4) is:

- The first time I change from light mode to dark mode, it works fine.
- When I change from dark mode back to light mode, the immediate children of the body don't update their background color right away.
- Often, but not always, these elements fix themselves when you scroll or take a screenshot.
- The children of the `<footer>` only fix themselves when you refresh the page.

When I asked a friend to take a look at it on his MacBook, he saw a different set of criteria, but the same basic problem.

I have taken some steps to mitigate this. For example, children of the `<footer>` don't need to be affected by this rule, so I added:

```css
footer * {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

However, any elements that are affected by `background-color: inherit` still display this problem.

I found that adding this piece of JavaScript to the function that changes the background color seems to fix it:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main');
main.hidden = true;
setTimeout(() => main.hidden = false, 1);
```

Bizarrely, the delay of `1` is required: if I set the delay to `0`, the children of the `<main>` have the correct background color but `<main>` itself doesn't, leading to incorrect colors in the margins.

Further, Chrome handles the background color change correctly out of the box, so I don't want to force it to blink. `navigator.userAgent` is unhelpful (every browser I've tried claims to be Mozilla and AppleWebKit and Safari and some other things); the only way I've found to reliably test for Safari is the deprecated `navigator.vendor === 'Apple Computer, Inc.'`.

With all of that background information out of the way, my question is: Why does Safari not like `background-color: inherit`, and what should I do about it? At some point it's easier to write repetitive CSS than try to work around the bug.

Comment: Could you provide a [small example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem?